# Possibility using gate authorization without logged user

Tags: php, laravel, php-7, laravel-6

Is there a possiblity to use Gate authorization without making use of user auth service?

For example I want to define a Gate:

```php
Gate::define('morning', function(){
    return date('H') < 12;
});
```

When I do `Gate::allows('morning')` or in the controller `$this->authorize('morning')` is returning always false because there is no user logged in.

How can I make this work for just guest users?

Comment: Middleware is a better solution, it does not require authorization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although there may be better solutions like using `middleware` or using `abort` helper function:

```php
abort_if(date('H') < 12, 403, 'This action is unauthorized.');
```

But there is [solution for policies](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization#guest-users) by declaring an "optional" type-hint or supplying a null default value for the user argument definition:

```php
class DatePolicy
{
    /**
     * Determine if it's morning now!
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return bool
     */
    public function morning(?User $user)
    {
        return date('H') < 12;
    }
}
```

It may work for gates too but I haven't test this:

```php
Gate::define('morning', function ($user = null) {
    return date('H') < 12;
});
```

Comment: adding the $user=null in the callback was the critical step. I was losing my mind, thanks.